# how many subsets in a set?

Tags: combinatorics

I know this is a pretty basic question, but I fail to understand the notion behind it.

Consider the following:

> If $A=\left\{a,b,c\right\}$, how many subsets can be created from $A$?

It is simple to write all possibilities and see it is $2^3=8$, but I don't understand why this is idea behind the formula.

Comment: you gave a set, not a group

Comment: @mathworker21 my bad, I will edit.

Comment: Think about it this way: Each element could be in the subgroup(really though, it makes more sense to say subset here), or it could not be in the subset. So for each element, there are two possibilities. Then we multiply all of the possibilities together, which is $(2)(2)(2) = 8.$ This works no matter how large the set is.

Comment: @MathIsLife12 thanks, that is clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say $A$ has $n$ elements (in your example $n=3$). To determine a subset of $A$, we go through each element of $A$ and decide whether to put it in our subset or to omit it from our subset. This creates two possible options for each element of $A$, which yields $2^n$ possible combinations once we go through all elements of $A$. Hence, $A$ has $2^n$ subsets.

Comment: Okay now I see it, this is the same as tossing a coin.

Comment: In terms of the two outcomes for the elements, yes.